# How to get the "price and image key" values from this DOMobject

Tags: php, json, xpath, web-scraping, simplexml

How to get the price and image values from this below.

> DOMElement Object ( [tagName] => script [schemaTypeInfo] => 
>   [nodeName] => script [nodeValue] => 
>      {"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"ItemList","itemListElement":[{"offers":{"priceCurrency":"Rs. ","@type":"Offer","price":"133998.00","availability":"https://schema.org/InStock"},"image":"https://static-01.daraz.pk/p/267cc89e2ff3e886b6bded905007d0a9.jpg","@type":"Product","name":"Galaxy Note 9 - 6.4\" - 6Gb Ram - 128Gb Rom - Dual Sim - Ocean Blue","url":"https://www.daraz.pk/products/samsung-galaxy-note-9-64-6gb-ram-128gb-rom-dual-sim-ocean-blue-i100262063-s1222963201.html?search=1"},{"offers":{"priceCurrency":"Rs. ","@type":"Offer","price":"111999.00","availability":"https://schema.org/InStock"},"image":"https://static-01.daraz.pk/original/1da238a72d721dd92c6db87176479b47.jpg","@type":"Product","name":"Galaxy S9+ - 6.2\" QHD+ - 6GB RAM - 128GB ROM - 12/12/8MP Camera - Titanium Gray","url":"https://www.daraz.pk/products/galaxy-s9-62-qhd-6gb-ram-128gb-rom-12128mp-camera-titanium-gray-i1487172-s9267151.html?search=1"}

Comment: Can you expand on the above a bit more? I'm not sure how you're trying to retrieve the values? You have an xPath tag but the above appears to be JSON

Comment: I'm trying to scrap a shopping site but it uses javascript to load the content. So after examining the page source I find the script tag which contains all the data. So I did this "$prices = $xpath->query('//script');" and in the price variable I have this json.

Comment: Can you show us *the HTML you're parsing* (not the whole page, just a [mcve])? It's hard to see what this debug output actually means.

Comment: I'm want to get the the price and image of products from this site [link]https://www.daraz.pk/smartphones/nokia/. But they are using javascript to load content and I'm doing normal scraping. So I examine the page source and at the end I find a script tag which contains all information about products so I scrap the script tag like this **$prices = $xpath->query('//script');** and now I have this Domelement object. How I get price and image values from this Object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep breaking your problem down, and solving one task at a time:

1. Find where on the page the content you want is. (Done.)
2. Ignoring what else is on the page, find a way to access that part. (Done.)
3. Ignoring the rest of that element, get just its string content. There's nothing else you need from the HTML at this point, so the DOM won't help you beyond this point.
4. Ignore everything about how you got it, and look at the structure of that string, and work out how to parse it. Hint: it looks like JSON, and PHP has built in functions for handling JSON.
5. Once you've parsed the string, get the pieces of information you want out of it. At this point, you won't even need to know what the string looked like, you'll just have a PHP array or object.